# Using MVVM in ListView on checking a checkbox show a label and on unchecking checkbox hide a label in the selected row - wpf

Tags: wpf, listview, checkbox, mvvm, show-hide

In my wpf application I am using MVVM. In ListView in selected row I want to show/ hide a label on checking/unchecking of a checkbox in the same selected row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the built-in BooleanToVisibilityConverter, and bind it to the Checkbox's IsChecked Property. See below for a simple example.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/    presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" Content="CheckBox"     VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"><    /CheckBox>
        <TextBlock Text="Label" Grid.Row="1"      VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,    ElementName=myCheckBox, Converter={StaticResource     BoolToVis}}"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: Checkbox unchecked]
[image: Checkbox checked]